# Redux validation before dispatching axios call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to pass a validation test before making an axios call, but not sure how to implement it correctly its either validation or sending request straight away.

In my main container named "main.jsx" i have

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    sendRequest: (query) => dispatch(request_house(query))
  };
};
```

and then in my actions

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes'
import serverConnect from "../../axios/connection";


export const set_house = (response) =>{
    return {
        type: actionTypes.SET_HOUSE,
        response,
    }
}
export const set_error = () =>{
    return {
        type: actionTypes.SET_ERROR
    }
}
export const validate_request = (query) =>{
    return {
        type: actionTypes.VALIDATE_REQUEST,
        query
    }
}
export const request_house = (query) =>{
    return dispatch =>{
        serverConnect.post(`/searchHouse/${query}`).then(response => {
            dispatch(set_house(response))
          }).catch(()=>{
            dispatch(set_error)
          });
    }

}
```

Is there a way to dispatch validation call before making a request? how should i approach this?

Comment: Do you want to chain actions? after validate_request action response, you want to dispatch request_house action?

Comment: You can do the chaining of actions in `redux observable` please refer https://redux-observable.js.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Redux doesn't support chaining of actions. That's where Redux-Thunk, Redux-Saga and other libraries come in to picture.

Check this [blog](https://decembersoft.com/posts/what-is-the-right-way-to-do-asynchronous-operations-in-redux/), which explain in detail about doing chaining or asynchronous operations with different libraries.